# Scons: run some script before scons

Tags: python, scons

I want to run some scripts/builders (depending on targets) at Scons startup, before it starts to create dependency.

What is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to access one of the variables `BUILD_TARGETS`, `COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS` and `DEFAULT_TARGETS`. They are further described in the UserGuide ( http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html ), sect. "SConscript Variables".
For your scripts, you can then do a simple check like:

```
  if 'my_special_target' in COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS:
      do_special_stuff()
```